# Trouble Booting Up after Crash Caused By Losing Power

Tags: boot

When attempting to boot, my computer get permanently stuck on sda6 : clean: xx blocks: xx message. I've attempted to fix this issue but am not having any luck.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1) Selected Recovery Mode option from Grub menu, then select continue with with normal boot. This brings me to the login page where I immediately get a system problem pop up message. Every time I attempt to login in, a pop up message flashes and I get returned back to the login prompt before being able to click report problem.

2) In grub menu, I have pressed 'e' then edited 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset quiet splash'. As far as I can tell this didn't do anything.

3) I have selected recovery mode option then proceeded to root option. I edited a file /etc/default/grub to do the same thing as in #2 I think. I forget how it I got to it, but I continued to a boot session with f 10. A lot of scripts showed up part of the boot process, and it got stuck on Start Show Plymouth Boot Screen.

Anyways I really have no clue what I should do. Currently I think if I am somehow able to clear my clash logs, then try to reboot in recovery mode that prompt won't display. I really only need one file, so even if I can't log in graphically, I would be okay with using some sort of terminal command to backup the file onto a usb possibly. Also this is on a partitioned hard drive. I can boot into Windows just fine.

Thanks for any help,

B

Comment: Your step 1 is fine and part of a normal troubleshooting (although expected not fix it in this case). Steps 2,3, in you case, at best do nothing but are more likely to make it worse. Keep in mind for the future that usually a forced shutdown may corrupt system partitions and that should be the focus when troubleshooting. Whenever you have video and login screen, **there's nothing wrong with Grub and `nomodeset`is absolutely NOT required.**

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`