# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes in the splash screen

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, bootloader, boot-repair

My friend has ubuntu 18.04 and it got frozen then he restarted the laptop but it stucks in the splash screen, this problem happened to him 2 days ago and when he reinstalled the grub it got fixed but it happened again and he tried to reinstall the grub boot loader using a USB live disk but it didn't fix the problem, is there another way to fix it?

Comment: Does it freeze on the Ubuntu logo with the rotating dots, or at some other point? How old is this laptop?

Comment: Yes, It freezes on the Ubuntu logo with the rotating dots, the laptop is 2.5 years old and installed ubuntu 2 months ago. @heynnema

Comment: it didn't work since the line is uncommented, but my friend tried one of your old answers https://askubuntu.com/a/938757/989248 and it seemed to work, thank you :D, and you can write the same answer and I will accept it since it has worked. @heynnema

Comment: I updated my answer. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`